# Using BSD jot for generating file with random content

Tags: shell, macos, bsd, random, seq

Quote from [Using BSD jot](https://administratosphere.wordpress.com/tag/jot/)

> Most every Linux system comes with GNU seq (a utility to generate
> sequences of numbers or characters). However, a much older utility –
> and more flexible one – is the underutilized and unknown utility, jot.
> Every BSD system, including MacOS X, will come with jot (and not with
> seq).

(...)

> In fact, to generate a large file (5Gb in this case), try this:
>
> ```
> jot -r -c -s '' $(( 1024 * 1024 * 5 )) > file.5gb
> ```

When I try this out it generates a 5 MB file.

```console
$ jot -r -c -s '' $(( 1024 * 1024 * 5 )) > file.5gb
$ du -sh file.5gb
5.0M    file.5gb
```

What does this command exactly do? How to specify size, for example 2 GB file? Is this the recommended way to generate random content files on macOS? Do you use other tools for random content files?

`seq` can't generate random content. Is this correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The example is slightly wrong and the result is correct. Let me explain.

The `$(( 1024 * 1024 * 5 ))` is simply a product, but it will only work under the `sh` shell environment. For example:

```
sh
echo $(( 1024 * 1024 * 5))
5242880
```

That part sorted, back to `jot`. The `-r` is for "random data" and that should be what you find in the file.

The `-c` is shorthand for, and the same as using `-w %c`. While I'm not exactly sure what `%c` means (*see comment by Bob Eager below for an answer*), it does seem to produce a single byte of random data. You could swap out the `-c` for `-b x` and you would get the same size file but it would contain just the `x` repeated.

Next is `-s ''` which means no line returns. Without this there would be a line return after each character (or random data). Your file should also be twice as big.

The next part is `$(( 1024 * 1024 * 5 ))`. This is the amount of "data" to produce. As shown above, that results in the number `5242880` (which is only 5MiB) and that is how large the file will be plus 1 byte for the trailing line return. For example:

```
sh
jot -r -c -s '' $(( 1024 * 1024 * 5 )) > file.5mb
ls -al file.5mb
-rw-r--r--  1 tigger  tigger  5242881  2 Apr 15:39 file.5mb
```

Comment: The `-c` (or `-w %c`) is a `printf` like construct. If one does not use it, one gets a stream of numbers. With it, one gets a stream of characters whose ASCII codes are those numbers.

Comment: `seq` cannot generate random content.